# How to start the service after restarting the device on Android 11?

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I want to start the service after restarting or turning on the device. At the moment everything works fine on my Android 8.1 device. But the Android 11 device does not launch my service, I do not get any errors. Here is my code:

Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<service
            android:name=".service.ServiceManager"
            android:exported="false" />

<receiver
            android:name=".receiver.AutoRebootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: FWIW, you cannot start background services from the background on newer versions of Android.

Comment: Is there any workaround to make the functionality of my application work after restarting the device?

Comment: I do not know what "the functionality of [your] application" is. What does the service do, is it a foreground service, and why are you trying to run it when the device boots?

Comment: This service monitors the installation and removal of other applications and offers to clear the cache, and this service also shows notifications to the user.

Comment: "This service monitors the installation and removal of other applications" -- I do not know why you need a service for that, let alone one that runs at boot time. You cannot find out about installation/removal by broadcasts anymore. For polling, you could use `WorkManager`, which can persist repeating work across reboots.